# C# Int16 data to Color while retaining human-readability, and precision

Tags: c#, image, math, colors, short

I am trying to represent a raw file full of 16-bit integers as an image in C#.

Here's the code that is in my 2 loops:

```
byte [ ] bigendian = new byte [ 2 ];
bigendian [ 1 ] = br . ReadByte ( );
bigendian [ 0 ] = br . ReadByte ( );
Int16 val = BitConverter . ToInt16 ( bigendian , 0 );
b . SetPixel ( x , y , Color . FromArgb ( 255 , Color . FromArgb ( val ) ) );
```

I have two images:
[image: Results]
Left is the result of the above code, right is a representation of the raw data i am using.

The problem is that on the left image, the colors seem to repeat themselves, when on the right image, they flow smoothly from black to white.

I can't use the right image because the colors are not mapped according to value, but according to the entire dataset.
This means that black on the right image is the lowest value of the data, and that white is the highest.
It is human readable, but it is impossible to get the original data back from the image.

What i want on the left one is that the value -32767 is black, and that the value 32767 is white, and i don't care if it's going to be grayscale or not (i can edit color in later).

I basically need some way to generate grayscale or RGB colors without looping colors over and over that preserves precision to allow conversion back to exact the same data, and is very basically human-readable (you can see peaks in the grid with the naked eye).

Comment: What do you mean by looping over and over? You need one loop to find the bounds and a second loop to write the data, right?

Comment: I thought on your question about 20 minutes, tried many variants. It seems that a) 16bit can't be compressed into 8bit; b) it's very hard to even imagine how picture should look to consider 16bits (I tried to think in RGB, HSL and HSB models). You should look at the formats that support 16bit per channel. I know only TIFF format

Comment: @NicoSchertler Once the value reaches the point that the last byte goes from 255 to 0, the second-last byte will only increase by one, the colour will look the same as 256 values back except just 1/256 of one colour channel.

Comment: @nsinreal i was more looking for scaling 16 bit up to 24 bit (to produce a RGB value)

Comment: @x13 it's not a problem to scale 16bit up to 24bit. It's a problem of creating human-readable picture. All color models that I know has a strict separation of pixel into 3 or 4 8bit components. So it's not a possible to create really good representation

Comment: @x13 best option that I see for you (except 16bit tiff) - make a picture partially human readable. So, your number is in range [-32767, 32768] or in range [0, 65535]. Instead of making perfect picture we can try another thing: make partially true picture and save another data in another components. So, let's take HSL model. Lightness in your calculation should be equal to number/256 or just significant 8bits of your number. The other 8bits you can save in both H-component (using first 4bits) and S-component (using second 4bits). This will create some noise, but picture will be readable

Comment: @x13 That's also will guarantee to you that you can restore back data from the picture.

Comment: @x13 Talking about noise introduced by H and S-components. We use only 4 bits per component, not all the 8 bits. 2^4=16, 2^8=256, 2^4/2^8=6.25%. This means that noise will be small (6.25% percents per channel) and it will allow to you interpret your picture.

Comment: @nsinreal thanks, i will certainly give it a try

Answer (score 1):

To account for your data being signed integers, where you want -32767 to be black, and 32767 to be white, you could first shift the data so that it ranges from 0 to 65535 (by adding 32,768), then splitting your 16-bit value into two 8-bit values for red and green channels, and duplicating the green channel for the last blue channel, like:

```
UInt32 unsignedInt = (UInt32)(BinaryReader.ReadInt16() + 32768);
byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(unsignedInt);
Color myRgbColor = new Color();
myRgbColor = Color.FromArgb(byteArray[0], byteArray[1], byteArray[1]);
b.SetPixel(x, y, myRgbColor);
```

Comment: If you split your value into the red and green channel, then you do not guarantee that it will be displayed "continuously" (or "smoothly"). For instance, 255 will translate to 0 in red channel and 255 in green channel, and 256 will translate to 1 in red channel and 0 in green channel. You'll see a clear separation between the two in the final picture, even though the difference in absolute value is only 1 (so  you're expecting to see them blend in smoothly). The split would need to be smarter, for instance 1 would be R=0;G=1, 2 would be R=1;G=1; 3 would be R=1;G=2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For user preview you must downgrade from 16 bit to 8 bits per channel but this way you loose precision (and it's impossible to recreate oryginal values). For saving raw data you can use TIFF as @nsinreal wrote or you must save your data in your own format that will preserve precision. Any method you choose at point when you want to do any preview in human readable way you will must convert it, at runtime, from 16 to 8bits